# Using CMake for compiling c++ with CUDA code

Tags: cmake, cuda

I am trying to add CUDA functions in existing C++ project which uses CMake.

For example, `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kernels/test.cuh"

int main() {
  wrap_test_print();
  return 0;
}
```

And `kernels/test.cu` looks like:

```
#include "test.cuh"
__global__ void test_print(){
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}

void wrap_test_print() {
  test_print<<<1, 1>>>();
  return;
}
```

And `kernels/test.cuh` looks like:

```
#ifndef TEST_CUH__
#define TEST_CUH__

#include <stdio.h>

void wrap_test_print();

#endif
```

And I use following codes for `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
===============
CMakeLists.txt
===============
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
enable_language(CUDA)
project(cmake_and_cuda)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(kernels)

# set_property(TARGET main 
#              PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(main kernels)

===============
kernels/CMakeLists.txt
===============
enable_language(CUDA)
add_library(kernels
test.cu
test.cuh
)
target_compile_features(kernels PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(kernels
                       PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(kernels)
```

However, when I use `cmake ..` in the `build` folder in the project, the following error message are printed:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CUDA_DEVICE_LINK_LIBRARY
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CUDA_DEVICE_LINK_LIBRARY
```

I guess this is due to a `cudart` problem, so I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lcudart")` but I could not resolve this issue. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

The [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command will initialize many CMake variables concerning your system and compiler. As such, it sets the **languages** that your CMake project will be using. Without specifying any language in the `project()` command, the defaults (`C` and `CXX`) are enabled:

```
# Initialize for C and C++ languages.
project(cmake_and_cuda)
```

You should typically place the first `project()` command directly after the `cmake_minimum_required()` call, to avoid such errors.  The [`enable_language()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html) is a light-weight call, typically used to enable *further* languages later on in the CMake project. So, you should re-arrange your CMake file to place the `enable_language()` call *after* the `project()` call, so that CMake has initialized its internal variables properly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
# Initialize for C and C++ languages.
project(cmake_and_cuda)
# Also, enable CUDA language support.
enable_language(CUDA)
```

Or, simply enable all the languages your CMake project needs in the `project()` command itself:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
# Initialize for C++ and CUDA languages.
project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
```

Note: The `enable_language()` and `project()` command's languages apply to all CMake directories below them, so there is no need to call `enable_language()` again in sub-directories.